# Google+ Hangouts API deprecation: what about the Hangouts button?

Tags: javascript, hangouts-api

I'm currently using a [Hangouts button](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button) in order to start video calls with pre-filled participants from a web app.

According to Google's latest deprecation notice, the whole Google+ Hangouts API will be soon dismissed, even though deprecation seems only to refer to custom Hangouts apps. My button instead is not meant to start a specific app, just a generic video call:

```js
gapi.hangout.render('tagId', {
  'render': 'createhangout',
  'invites': [...],
  'widget_size': 34
});
```

Based on these premises, will I still be able to start a call this way?